# Download Mono-complete

Tags: ubuntu, mono

**I want to Download (not install) Mono-complete for ubuntu 14.04 as well as ubuntu 12.04 .**

- Please Suggest How can i download? (my goal is to install it later on other system without internet. )
- And which mono-complete version is best suited for ubuntu 14.04 and
  for ubuntu 12.04 platform.so that it gives complete/satisfactory
  memory management or garbage collection.
- When i run .Net AppLication by Mono-Complete version 3.2.8 downloaded from synaptic ,it runs the application but gives mono-sgen crashed with SIGABRT error.But on the same lines when i run application from Sudo application runs but it does not crash but red circle comes on the desktop.I used modern dlls in my application

Answer (score 1):

go into an empty directory. then either download `mono-complete` with `apt-get download` as far as I know it doesn't cover dependencies, but it also works if you have the package currently installed. 
second possibility is to do

```
apt-get --download-only -o Dir::Cache="./" -o Dir::Cache::archives="./" install mon-complete
```

to download mono and all of its dependencies **which are required on this system** as .deb packages

alternatively you can use something like keryx, an offline package manager. see [the question on askubuntu.com for more information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)